# Why is string.empty() evaluating to true when the string contains a value?

Tags: c++, string, mfc

**Introduction**

I am making an application using mfc that has a dialog box used to sort data in a spreadsheet. The dialog contains several controls including edit boxes. when the user clicks the OK button, the dialog should retrieve their preferences and close.

**Issue**

When getting the information from the dialog boxes, the strings containing the information are always registering as empty. I set a breakpoint at the location that the strings are located at, and the values seem to be found fine, but when I call any function to determine the size of the strings, it shows as 0.

**Code**

```
std::string min;
std::string max;
MinEdit.GetWindowText(&min[0], 20);
MinVal = atof(min.c_str());

MaxEdit.GetWindowText(&max[0], 20);
MaxVal = atof(max.c_str());

if (min.empty())
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Please Enter A Minimum Value"));
    return;
}

if (max.empty())
{
    AfxMessageBox(_T("Please Enter A Maximum Value"));
    return;
}
```

**Question**

Why do these strings always register as empty? I checked their length, which is returned as zero, yet when I check MinVal and MaxVal they have the value that was entered into the edit box. How can these strings be able to initialize the other variables with a value, when they are showing as empty?

Comment: When in MFC it's best to use `CString`. `CWnd::GetWindowText` has an overload that takes a `CString&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the error.

```
std::string min;
MinEdit.GetWindowText(&min[0], 20);
```

The string has no length, and you ask GetWindowText to write into that buffer.  That's an overrun and it causes undefined behavior.

Instead, allocate some space in the string, then resize it afterwards:

```
std::string min;
min.resize(20);
min.resize(MinEdit.GetWindowText(&min[0], min.size()));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a `std::string` to a function requiring a character array without first setting the buffer size, then resizing the string after the call.

```
min.resize(20);
MinEdit.GetWindowText(&min[0], 20);
min.resize(strlen(&min[0]));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is your bug:

```
MinEdit.GetWindowText(&min[0], 20);
```

The string is still empty, and the statement writes into random, unallocated memory. If you need to write into a C++ `std::string` from a C API, you first need to manually resize it:

```
min.resize(static_cast<size_t>(MinEdit.GetWindowTextLength()));
MinEdit.GetWindowText(&min[0], min.size());
```

Or, taking advantage of the RAII idiom:

```
std::string min(MinEdit.GetWindowText(),
                static_cast<size_t>(MinEdit.GetWindowTextLength()));
```

As an aside, you really want to use `std::wstring` with the Windows API (or MFC). It maps to the native character encoding used throughout Windows.